# Is the particle "to" part of the modal "verb need" or the lexical verb "clean" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm not sure if I should analyze the modal verb *need* with the particle *to* or without it in this sentence:
*We **need to clean** our room.*

Comment: No: "to" is part of the _to_-infinitival clause "to clean our room", which is complement of "need". Note that "need" is a not a modal auxiliary verb in your example, but a **lexical** verb. It is only a modal auxiliary when it has a bare infinitival clause as complement, as in "We needn't tell her."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the modal verbs **must** and **can**, there is no **to**: *We must clean*, *We can clean*. So I'd say the **to** belongs to the **need**.

Another way to analyze this is to make hypothetical sentences like these:

Clean the room if you **must**.

Clean the room if you **can**.

Clean the room if you **need to**.

Comment: If you have a hankering to, you can analyze "Clean the room if you need to" as an omission/deletion: "Clean the room if you need to [clean the room]".

Comment: That said, I'm not happy with the contemporary analysis of **to**.